# File INSTALL cannot set permissions on libippicv

Tags: linux, opencv

I am attempting to install OpenCV on Ubuntu. When running

> sudo cmake -DWITH_IPP=ON . && make -j $(nproc) && make install

I get the error:

> Install the project...
>   -- Install configuration: "RELEASE"
>   -- Up-to-date: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/libippicv.a
>   CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:36 (FILE):
>     file INSTALL cannot set permissions on
>     "/usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/libippicv.a"

Whats going wrong and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: in case you don't have sudo privileges you can check https://askubuntu.com/questions/2167/how-to-build-application-without-sudo-privileges

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sudo` only applies to the first command out of the three.  Really, you only want to run the install step as root, so put `sudo` on the third command instead.